# How to test collabora online performances

Tags: performance-testing, casperjs

I setuped collabora online, and the users complain about performances.
I'd like to be able to graph performances to be able to correlate to other monitoring graphs.

Here is an open document you can access:
https://cloud.pierre-o.fr/s/qnkheXaoBQV97EH

I'd like to be able to time the appearance of the document.
I tried various ways, but it is really tricky.

Here is one attempte with casperjs:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.options.waitTimeout = 30000;

casper.start('https://cloud.pierre-o.fr/s/qnkheXaoBQV97EH', function() {
  this.waitForSelector('div#StateWordCount', function() {
    this.echo('the document is loaded');
  }, function _onTimeout(){
    this.capture('screenshot.png');
  });
})

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
  this.echo("Error:    " + msg, "ERROR");
  this.echo("file:     " + trace[0].file, "WARNING");
  this.echo("line:     " + trace[0].line, "WARNING");
  this.echo("function: " + trace[0]["function"], "WARNING");
  errors.push(msg);
});

casper.run()
```

As you guess, I just get the screenshot without the document.

```
phantomjs  --version 
2.1.1
casperjs --version
1.1.3
```

I use the recent versions. I guess it is related to websocket, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, this also fails even with a huge timeout

```
casper.options.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height:800};

casper.test.begin('TEST DOC', 2, function (test) {

  casper.start("https://cloud.pierre-o.fr/s/qnkheXaoBQV97EH", function () {
      test.assertTitle("Nextcloud");
  });

  casper.waitUntilVisible("div#StateWordCount", function() {
      test.assertExists("Test!", "Found test text");
  }, function() {
      casper.capture("fail.jpg")
  }, 150000);

  casper.run(function () {
      test.done();
  });

});
```

It shows the following screen:

[image]

I would try [slimerjs](https://slimerjs.org/) as it looks like it might be a web socket issue!